# How to get flag in case of existing record in association in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a model A with a 1:N association to a model B. I want to get all records from A, and true if there exists at least one associated record from B, false otherwise.

The associations:

```
ModelA.hasMany(ModelB)
ModelB.belongsTo(ModelA)
```

The query:

```
const results = await ModelA.findAll({
include: { model: ModelB, required: false }
})
```

This way I am able to get the matching records from B if they exist (with the outer join), but I'm not really interested in records from B, I only want to know if they exist. Is there a way to generate the required `SELECT` query to get directly true/false based on the result of the join?
My desired query would be:

```
SELECT a.*, CASE WHEN b.id IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END
FROM modelA a LEFT OUTER JOIN modelB b on b.model_a_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `CASE WHEN` support in Sequelize yet, so you need to use `literal`.

```js
const results = await ModelA.findAll({
  attributes: {
    include: [
      [Sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN "b"."id" IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END'), 'b_exists']
    ]
  },
  include: { 
    model: ModelB,
    attributes: [],  // add this to remove ModelB data in response
    required: false
  }
})
```